# CICS: can SYSIDNT be echoed in GMTEXT at startup?

Tags: jcl, cics

I'm a newbie at this. In my CICS startup JCL I am setting a `SYSIDNT` of `SYSIDNT=Hip1`. Is it possible to echo this out to the terminal on startup just like I have found I can do with other things like `&SYSUID` and `&APPLID`?

If I have something like this:

```
SYSIDNT=Hip1
GMTEXT='CICS: &SYSUID, &APPLID, &RELEASE at'
```

Then I see something *like* this:

```
CICS: HIPPO01, IJCKBCDM, 730 at 10:47:11
```

But I cannot get `Hip1` echoed out... and I'd like to know if that is possible to achieve. I see **Hip1** echoed to screen once CICS is up and running and I'm using various transactions, so I'm positive it's set correctly - it's just that I can't see to tag it onto the `GMTEXT`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I got something I'm happy with by using an `EXPORT` and a `SET` statement for a new Symbol - I called `SYSTEMID` - and then assigned that to `SYSIDNT` and included it within the `GMTEXT` via `&SYSTEMID`.

```
//MYEXP  EXPORT SYMLIST=(SYSTEMID)
//STEP1 SET SYSTEMID=HIP1
```